# Similar YUM program for windows 7

Tags: windows, yum

I'm looking for some package manager for my web server.
I wonder to know is there any program same as YUM for windows 7?
TNX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a solution named chocolatay http://chocolatey.org. I never try it personally but I heard about it during puppet windows conf. You can find slides here http://www.slideshare.net/PuppetLabs/puppet-and-windowspuppetconf2013

---

UPDATE: I'm just trying it atm, and it's really nice solution. Is not yum but it's the closest way to simulate yum on windows.

Moreover if your program you want to install has a msi package it's easy to create your own package.

Comment: This looks pretty cool Kakawait, I had never heard of it until now.

Comment: There is a limitation due to Windows OS but it's work nicely. And creating package or not so hard, in major case it's just a ps1 (powershell script) script.

Comment: Yea it seems very cool from the little I checked out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software called "win-get".

win-get is an automated install system and software repository for Microsoft Windows written in pascal (for the command line client) and php for the online repository. The ideas for its creation come from apt-get and other related tools for the *nix platforms.

The system works by connecting to a link repository. Finding an application and downloading it from the stored link using wget.exe . Then performing the installation routine (silent or standard). And finnally deleting the install file.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/windows-get/